# How to use same serializer class for get and post method in Django?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have been trying, but fail miserably, to use only a single serializer class for both post and get api call. I have a Person model which has some fields. What I need is I want to create a person object using post API with certain fields and however needs to show some other fields while doing get request. For eg:

My model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    roll = models.IntegerField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
```

Now my serializer will look like this.

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ['id','email','name','phone','roll','subject','college_name', 'address']
```

For eg, I have a view that handles both post and get request (probably using APIView), then what I need to do is, to create a person object I only using name, phone, and email. So for post API call, I only need three fields whereas while calling the get API I only need to display the fields name, roll, subject, and college_name not others.

In this situation, how can I handle using the same serializer class??

Comment: Could you please include your `views` code also? And the `student` model too

Answer (score 3):

You can set fields to be read-only (for GET requests) with the `read_only_fields` list and write-only (for POST, PUT, PATCH) with the `extra_kwargs` dictionary, both inside the Serializer's Meta class:

```python
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'name', 'phone', 'roll', 'subject', 'college_name']
        read_only_fields = ['roll', 'subject', 'college_name']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'email': {'write_only': True},
            'phone': {'write_only': True},
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

First in the model, you need to add the attribute `null=True` into the non-required fields.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    # here I added `null=True`
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null = True)
    roll = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null = True)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null = True)
```

And in the serializer, you need to add the `extra_kwargs` property to set the read-only fields.

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'name', 'phone', 'roll', 'subject', 'college_name']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'roll': {'read_only': True},
            'subject': {'read_only': True},
            'college_name': {'read_only': True},
        }
```

Comment: What if some fields are common>? That means I need email and phone for both the request

Comment: You can both read and write the normal fields if not specified.